# In AWS SQS, Attribute is visible in console and not able to read it programatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am trying to insert a token in SQS using "AWS Service Proxy" in Web API with Path Override given as below :

Account#/QueueName?Action=SendMessage&MessageAttribute.1.Name="TEST"&MessageAttribute.1.Value.StringValue="abcd"&MessageAttribute.1.Value.DataType=String&Version=2012-11-05&Expires=2100-05-05T22%3A52%3A43PST

I can see this attribute "TEST" created with value "abcd" in the console of SQS but when I try to  retrieve it thru code, I am not able to get the attribute "TEST". Code I am using to retrieve is given below"

```
sqs.receiveMessage({
    QueueUrl: sqsQueueUrl,
    MaxNumberOfMessages: 3, // how many messages do we wanna retrieve?
    VisibilityTimeout: 60, // seconds - how long we want a lock on this job
    WaitTimeSeconds: 3, // seconds - how long should we wait for a message?
    AttributeNames: ["All"]
}, function (err, data) {
    // If there are any messages to get
    if (data.Messages) {
        // Get the first message (should be the only one since we said to only get one above)
        var message = data.Messages[0],
            body = JSON.parse(message.Body);
        // Now this is where you'd do something with this message
        context.done("Message Found");
    }
});
```

Please let me know what I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your code are you attempting to get the value of the attributes. You are simply accessing `message.Body`. You need to access `message.Attributes`.

Comment: I have checked the attributes associated with the message. The attribute "TEST" was not there. Replacing "All" with "TEST" does not returns any token while in console I can clearly see the "TEST" attribute.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't show that. Show the actual code that isn't working in your question if you want someone to help you.